# How to consume a WCF service with SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: wcf, ssrs-2008

Are there any good tutorials available for querying for WCF services from within SSRS?

My WCF service is running fine, but when I try to query it from SSRS, I get contract mismatch exceptions. Some Googling suggests that querying WCF services in SSRS 2008 R2 is possible, but there doesn't seem to be any good documentation available. Help!

Comment: Take a look at this as well. http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/wcf-service-as-datasource-in-ssrs/. Also this. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37270/Consuming-a-WCF-Service-from-an-SSRS-RDL-Server-Re

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It took a while but I got it done! A lot of blog posts were helpful but not end-to-end, so in the spirit of paying it forward, here's [my blog post](http://vishalbardoloidev.blogspot.com/2011/09/using-wcf-web-services-as-data-source.html) to walk through the process.

Comment: Awesome. Still relevant and helped me today!

Comment: Link is no longer valid

Answer (score 2):

You can go through this links

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WcfSSRSEx1.aspx
   http://weblogs.asp.net/jezell/archive/2008/02/21/using-wcf-endpoints-with-sql-reporting-services.aspx