# SSRS Report Consuming RESTful Web Service

Tags: xml, rest, reporting-services, restful-url, ssrs-2017

I am trying to consume an XML via a REST web service using SSRS. I am intending to create the XML using LINQ and then dump it at the web service location.

The web service is held in Azure under

> https:// ... azurewebsites.net/api/simpleXmlData?name=Test

In the report, I have created a data source with the type XML and the connection string as the above, with the parameter determined separately like below.

> "https:// ... azurewebsites.net/api/simpleXmlData?name=" & Parameters!Id.Value

I have then created a dataset, which attempts to call it using the method XML query type: [image: XML query type].

```
<Query>
   <Method Name="Club" 
Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
   <Parameters>
       <Parameter Name="Item">
           <DefaultValue>/</DefaultValue>
       </Parameter>
   </Parameters>
   </Method>
   <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

However, when I debug the report, upon opening I get this [image: error].

I am new to this and have read up as much as I can, mainly basing the report on what I've seen below:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964129%28SQL.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
- http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/webservice-as-datasource-in-ssrs/
- https://www.teamscs.com/2015/12/consuming-a-web-service-in-a-ssrs-report/
- [Consume web api in SSRS with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790123/consume-web-api-in-ssrs-with-parameter)

We prefer to use REST over SOAP as the latter appears to be more time consuming to use.

Is there a solution to this or is REST still not supported by Reporting Services?

Comment: I know this is old, but for anyone else who finds their way here, I was able to get this to work according to the examples in the first link above. One 'gotcha' in that documentation though is this part: _"XML content can also be accessed directly from a URL. Notice that only the HTTP protocol is supported and the request uses the GET method. However, if parameters are specified, the POST method will be used."_ Not exactly RESTful by strict standards, but after changing my API method to a POST, the report worked.